# ¿cargar crystal reports con datos de gridview?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, crystal-reports

Tengo un gridview en asp .net llenado con un datatable y necesito que al dar click a un boton imprimir me genere un reporte crystal reports con los datos del gridview. Estuve investigando y al parecer es con un "dataset tipado", no entiendo muy bien como hacerlo.

Asi he llenado mi gridview

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ToString());
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from table where cod_user='"+ Session["Cod_user"]+"'", con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
gridview1.Visible = true;
gridview1.DataSource = dt;
gridview1.DataBind();
con.Close();
```

Ahora se supone que con esos datos me genere un reporte al dar click a un boton.

> Utilizo webform.aspx con c#

Answer (score 0):

Tengo lo que necesitas de una aplicación vieja, esta en visual basic, pero te da la lógica de lo que debes hacer:

```
        Dim parametro As New ParameterValues
        Dim tipo As New ParameterDiscreteValue
        Dim reporte As New rpt_puestos
        Dim con_base As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Dim adp_div As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        Dim puesto As New DataTable
        Dim sqlcadena As String
        con_base.ConnectionString = Application("cadena").ToString
        sqlcadena = "select * from tabla"

        adp_div = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlcadena, con_base)
        puesto = New DataTable
        adp_div.Fill(puesto)
        reporte.SetDataSource(puesto)
        puesto = New DataTable
        adp_div.Fill(puesto)
        parametro.Add(tipo)
        tipo.Value = "TITULO REPORTE"      

        puesto.Dispose()
        con_base.Dispose()
        adp_div.Dispose()
        reporte.DataDefinition.ParameterFields("titulo").ApplyCurrentValues(parametro)        
        reporte.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, True, tipo.Value.ToString.Replace(" ", "_"))
        Response.[End]()
        reporte.Dispose()
```

Lo que te falta es darle al origen de datos del reporte la tabla que ya has obtenido de la consulta, si el reporte lleva otros parámetros como titulo o algo mas, esta el ejemplo de como pasarlos y finalmente el reporte se exporta en formato pdf, pero esto se puede cambiar de acuerdo a lo que se necesite.

En resumen: 
Debes agregar las referencias de crystal reports

Debes crear el reporte con el diseñador de cristal reports y guardarlo en alguna carpeta de la aplicacion

Si el reporte lleva parametros deberas agregarlos en el codigo, si no con el solo origen de datos es suficiente

agregar la tabla al datasource del reporte

Exportar el reporte

(El codigo en c# es muy similar)

Comment: Carlos hola gracias por responder, pero ciertamente no entiendo a tu codigo, soy muy muy principiante en esto aun

Comment: @sunflower edite la respuesta a ver si te queda mas claro